# How to Run JXCORE

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jxcore

I am trying to run jxcore. but i am not able to.Please help me out as i am new to this.

**server.js**

```
var http = require("http");

jxcore.tasks.on('message', function (threadId, param)  {   
    console.log('Main thread received a message from subthread no ' +
                   threadId + '. Message: ', param);
});

http.createServer(function(req,resp) {
    console.log("Listening To Thread " + process.threadId);   
    resp.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});    
    resp.end("Running JXCORE "+process.threadId);
}).listen(3000);
```

**serverjx.js**

```
var method = function() {
    try  {
        process.keepAlive();
        require("server");
        console.log("Welcome To NodeJS");
        return {
            someResult: "some result";
        };
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Error Occured : "+e);
        return {"Error":e};
    }
}

jxcore.tasks.runOnce(code, {count:1000}, function(obj) {
    process.sendToMain({started:true});
    console.log("Return Value " + obj);

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("Waiting For TimeOut 5 Sec");
    }, 5000);
});
```

and i am typing on cmd as `jx server.js jx mt-keep server.js`

I am not seeing thread running. please help

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of structural mistakes here. Plus it is not obvious, what you're trying to do.

**Scenario 1** - running only *server.js*

they both work: `jx mt server.js` or `jx mt-keep server.js`

**Scenario 2** - running *serverjx.js* which loads for each thread *server.js*

Here probably you try to create an http server on each thread by using `jxcore.tasks.runOnce()`. So each of the threads would load *server.js* and create it's own instance of http server there.

This should be launched this way: `jx serverjx.js` (without mt or mt-keep)

Although I don't see the point to do it this way (why not running it as in Scenario 1 since it is the correct approach for a multithreaded http server?), after few fixes the code would look like this:

*serverjx.js*:

```
var method = function () {
    try {
        process.keepAlive();
        require("./server");
        console.log("Welcome To NodeJS");
        return {
            someResult: "some result"
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error Occured : " + e);
        return {"Error": e};
    }
};

jxcore.tasks.runOnce(method, {count: 1000});
```

Please note few things:

- `require('server')` is wrong if you try to load *server.js* - you have to call `require('./server')`
- `jxcore.tasks.runOnce(code, ...)` is wrong - should be `jxcore.tasks.runOnce(method, ...)`
- `jxcore.tasks.runOnce` does not receive callback argument, so I removed this.

Another thing is that in your callback you were trying to send an object to main thread (`process.sendToMain({started:true})`), but you have located the listener in *server.js* (`jxcore.tasks.on('message')`) which in fact gets loaded into a thread (so it is not the main thread) and the message could not arrive there.